# $f(n) = O(g(n))$ implies $g(n) = O(f(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

How do I prove/disprove $f(n) = O(g(n))$ implies $g(n) = O(f(n))$?

I got to $f(n) \le c * g(n)$ easily enough from the definition of Big O, but I'm not sure how to get to $c*f(n) \ge g(n)$.

Comment: Sometimes people misuse $O$ when they mean $\Theta$. That might lead to it seeming like the implication is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NO. $f(x)=x, g(x)=x^2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Ah. That would explain why I was stuck. I kept trying to prove it, when I should be disproving it.